# How many $4\times 3$ matrices of rank three are there over a finite field of three elements?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $M$ be the space of all $4\times 3$ matrices with entries in the finite field of three elements. Then the number of matrices of rank three in $M$ is
>
> A. $(3^4 - 3)(3^4 - 3^2)(3^4-3^3)$
>
> B. $(3^4 - 1)(3^4 - 2)(3^4 - 3)$
>
> C. $(3^4-1)(3^4-3)(3^4-3^2)$
>
> D. $3^4(3^4 - 1)(3^4 - 2)$

Is there any specific formula to solve this type of problem? Is there any specific formula to calculate the number of matrices? I have no idea how to start this problem. Any guidance please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the previous post.the answer I am getting is c

$(3^4-1)(3^4-3)(3^4-3^2)$

For the $1$st column we have $4$ places and $3$ elements to fill it.So $3^4$ choices but the elements can't be all zero.S0 we have $3^4-1$ choices .For the second column  we have $3^4$ choices but the second column cant be linearly dependent with the $1$st .So $(3^4-3)$ choices .Similarly the $3$rd column is not linearly dependent to both $1$st and $2$ nd cloumn

Comment: @vadim123 A matrix and its transpose have the same rank.

Comment: thankx @learnmore your answer is correct.

Comment: I didn't understood the second column thing. How $3^4-3$. Can you elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 1):

A $4$ $\times$ $3$ matrix of rank $3$ has $3$ linearly independent rows. Thus this problem can be restated to find the number of unordered linearly independent subsets of cardinality 3 in ${{\mathbb{Z}_3}^3}({\mathbb{Z}_3)}$. So there are precisely ($3^4$−1)($3^4$−3)($3^4$−$3^2$) such matrices.